# LINQ DataTable Sum In Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having a rough time figuring out exactly how to do a LINQ query on a DataTable and return a full row while having the WHERE clause test on a sum.

My code:

```
transactionsToRemove.AddRange(paymentTransactionResults
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Where(...)
     .GroupBy(r => (decimal)r["AccountNumber"]));
```

There are multiple transactions for each AccountNumber, and I need to sum those together and determine whether they're less than a user inputted amount (For my purpose, it's called balanceGreaterThan). I can't find any examples to go by where someone has done this sort of thing.

Thanks in advance, SO.

**Edit**: My apologies -- The column I need to sum is called "Balance"

**Edit 2**: Final code

```
transactionsToRemove.AddRange(paymentTransactionResults
     .AsEnumerable()
     .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("AccountNumber"))
     .Where(g => g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Balance")) < balanceGreaterThan)
     .SelectMany(g => g));
```

I had to change the GroupBy to use r.Field rather than r["AccountNumber"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to filter the groups themselves (to find which groups have a large sum), not the rows that go into the groups.
Therefore, you need to put the `Where()` call after the `GroupBy`:

```
transactionsToRemove.AddRange(paymentTransactionResults
     .AsEnumerable()
     .GroupBy(r => (decimal)r["AccountNumber"])
     .Where(g => g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Balance") < balanceGreaterThan));
```

**EDIT**: If you want to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` back  (as opposed to an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DataRow>>`), you'll need to add `.SelectMany(g => g)`.

Comment: Wow, SLaks is trying to be extremely picky with every other answer to get his own upvoted. Sly!

Comment: @Timwi: I do this to most answers, even if I'm not competing with them.  This is a fairly beginner-level question, so it's important to get the details right. Also, I didn't downvote anything.

Comment: Yeah, I needed IEnumerable<DataRow> back. You've been more than helpful. Full code posted above.

Comment: OK, out of curiosity, where does your `AsEnumerable()` come from? There is no such method on `System.Data.DataTable`, and nor does it implement any interface that has this as an extension method?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't perform LINQ queries on non-typed DataTables without the AsEnumerable().

Comment: @Timwi: It's an extension method on DataTable defined in `System.Data.DataTableExtensions`, in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll.

Answer (score 3):

```
transactionsToRemove.AddRange(paymentTransactionResults
     .AsEnumerable()
     .GroupBy(r => (decimal)r["AccountNumber"])
     .Where(g => g.Sum(r => (decimal)r["Balance"]) <= someInput)
     .SelectMany(g => g));
```

Comment: Won't compile.  `g` isn't an `IEnumerable<decimal>`.

Comment: Try now - I've included `SelectMany` :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it on some wrong input data (not on a DataTable). I think it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
transactionsToRemove.AddRange(paymentTransactionResults 
     .AsEnumerable() 
     .GroupBy(r => (decimal)r["AccountNumber"])); 
     .Where(grp => grp.Sum(r => r["amount"]) < balanceGreaterThan);
```